# Upgrading AisleRiot Solitaire

Tags: software-installation, games

I'm having [some trouble](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=766217) with AisleRiot Solitaire. Well, it seems that I must upgrade it to a version >= 3.16. But I don't know how to do that. I tried to remove and reinstall it, but after the re-installation, the version is the same as it was (3.10.2), and the bug remains...

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Comment: Hi Larara, could you please edit your post to include what version of Ubuntu you're using?

Comment: @NickWeinberg done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upgrade *relatively* painlessly to Aisleriot 3.16.2 by following these steps:

**Activate Sources:**

You need to allow Trusty to retrieve the development files used to build the newer version of Aisleriot. Follow this train:

```
Dash > Software & Updates > Ubuntu Software > Downloadable from The Internet > Source Code
```

Click on the 'Source Code' check box to *activate* it and then close the 'Software & Updates' box; you will be prompted to reload your Software Sources, allow this to happen.

Then open a Terminal screen and run the following:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep aisleriot
```

This will download about 40 mb or so of development files.

**Build Aisleriot:**

Copy and paste the *entire* following code box into a Terminal screen and a semi-automated download, compile and install will take place:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall && \
mkdir -v $HOME/Desktop/aisleriot_build && cd $HOME/Desktop/aisleriot_build && \
wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/aisleriot/3.16/aisleriot-3.16.2.tar.xz && \
tar xvf aisleriot-3.16.2.tar.xz && cd aisleriot-3.16.2 && \
./configure && make && \
sudo checkinstall --pakdir "$HOME/Desktop/aisleriot_build" \
     --backup=no --deldoc=yes --pkgname aisleriot --pkgversion 3.16.2 \
     --fstrans=no --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default
```

I found when I built this that I had to log out and back in for Dash to find Aisleriot and then all was well.

A bonus of using `checkinstall` in this way is that the Aisleriot package is integrated into the Ubuntu package management system. Not as good as a formal Debian package but perfectly good for our purposes...

**Cleaning Up:**

If you would like to remove the build directory `$HOME/Desktop/aisleriot_build` simply delete it from your Desktop, it is no longer required...

**Play the game:**

Well, it is running fine here:

[image]

Hopefully running well on your system too :)

Comment: Do you recommend me to, before doing this, remove the old aisleriot?

Comment: It should not be required as the newer version will uninstall the older. But there is no harm in uninstalling first :)

Comment: YEAH!!! It worked! And the informations about my old games were not erased. Thanks [VERY](http://i.imgur.com/hbDcYsZ.gif) much

Comment: Great news :). You could perhaps experiment with newer versions but if this one works I would stay with it....

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't know of an easy way to get a newer version of AisleRiot working under 14.04 (maybe someone else does, and can chime in).

The software that's part of an Ubuntu LTS release is designed to work together smoothly, and unfortunately that comes as a trade-off against having the latest versions of software (though security updates are backported).

If/when you decide to upgrade your system to Ubuntu 16.04, it does come with AisleRiot Version 3.18.2 by default.

I wish I could be of more help, and I hope that if someone has a better answer, like how to use an updated Gnome-Games PPA or something for Trusty, they will share.

Comment: It would be strange if it isn't possible to upgrade under 14.04. Anyway, thanks for answering!